# Thunderbird Deleted Inbox File

Tags: thunderbird, file-recovery

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird. I tried to move mails to local part. Because the box had been very heavy. Some mails weren't being opened and deleted. So after I moved the inbox mails to local, I would delete inbox file.

I sent inbox file to recycle bin and loaded back. But now some of mails had been lost. I tried some recovery tools to get back the inbox file but didn't work.

It seems a file recovery problem rather than deleted mails. Windows's previous file option hadn't be enabled. Is there any other way to get the previous version of a file?